# Repotting sunflower to bigger pot?

Tags: houseplants, sunflowers

This is what my sunflower plant looks like. Its in a 4" pot.

Should I repot it to a larger pot? I've been told that a sunflower in a pot (like mine) will eventually die, so I'm not sure if repotting it to a bigger pot is worth it.

Is it true that potted sunflowers eventually die?
[image]

Comment: Roots look indeed they need more space. Sunflowers are annuals, so at the end of the season they will die anyways.

Comment: Thanks. When you say "they will die anyways" do you mean that the flower will die, or that the whole plant will die, as in throwing away the whole pot because there's nothing alive?

Comment: What I mean is that at the end of the summer, when all the seeds are formed in the flowers, the plant will die. It is an annual plant, which means it only lives for one year. For next year you'll need to buy a new plant or sow.

Comment: When growing sunflowers for the purpose of harvesting consumable seeds,  is there an ideal pot size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sunflowers have a lifecycle of a few months. They sprout, grow tall, grow a flower, and then they die. You might be able to extend the lifecycle a bit with special care indoors, or you can trick the plant into sprouting in the middle of winter, but that is it's lifecycle and at some point it will die.

Up-potting will help give new nutrients to the plants which is something you need to periodically do. Whether it's really worthwhile to re-pot it or not is up to your personal preferences. Keeping it in the same pot the size of the plant will stay a little smaller and it might start turning yellow or otherwise "looking sad" from the confined conditions and old soil.

Good luck, and enjoy the flower while it exists!